# Why I cannot quit the window using `quit-window`?

Tags: buffers, window

Say I have two existing files named "file1.el" and "file2.el".

Then I perform the following steps:

1. I open a file named "file1.el"
2. `C-x C-f` a file named "file2.el", now currently I have 1 window and it displays the "file2.el" buffer.
3. I use `eval-expression` an expression `(display-buffer "file1.el")`, it opens a new window that displays `file1.el` buffer on the same frame.
4. I **want to** kill the `file1.el` buffer and its corresponding window, so I `eval-expression` an expression `(quit-window t (get-buffer-window "file1.el"))`, and I got what I want.

However, things are different when I do some buffer switches on the window displaying "file1.el", just after step 3. If I have done it, the step 4 will only kill the "file1.el" buffer, but **NOT quitting** the window that displaying it. Instead, after step 4, that window will display another buffer that I've switch to previously.

My question is that why `quit-window` behavior is different in this scenario?

Comment: `quit-window` uses `quit-restore-window` to decide what to do: see their doc strings with `C-h f quit-window` and `C-h f quit-restore-window`.

Comment: Wht do you mean by window - a window as used by the operating system which emacs calls a frame - or an emacs window which is in a frame.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Drew Thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @NickD for the hint. The reason why `quit-window` does not quit the window is that, each window itself maintains a history of the buffers it has displayed. And the implementation of `quit-restore-window` makes use of it, from "(elisp) Quitting Windows":

> If prev-buffer is still live when quitting window, quitting the window may reuse window to display prev-buffer

Comment: Could you, by any chance, figure out a sane way to ignore that, and just get rid of the window regardless (even if prev-buffer would then have no window, or (if it implies that) would need to get reassigned to another)?